# Payment method creation observer

Tags: events, magento

I am currently creating a module that allows a back end user to manage customer's allowed payment methods. Magento event/observer helps a lot - everything that I need to do about customers hooked nicely by this system and transfers to my code. But I also need to hook an **event of payment method creation** (registering new payment method module). I know that there is no such event in Magento (correct me if I'm wrong), but I need some workaround to achieve such a functionality (nice/right way).

So here is a question:

*What is the best (nice/right) way to manage (hook) an event of payment method creation (payment module registering) in Magento?*

Sorry for the bad language... Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module install occurs quite early in application initialization; in fact, it occurs before the event areas are parsed, so there is no way to trigger the event observer.  See `Mage_Core_Model_App::run()`. Notice how `loadAreaPart()` (which triggers loading of event observer configuration) is called *after* `_initModules()` (in which we find the module install call `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()`). Standard event dispatching would therefore be pointless.

From a general app design perspective I'd argue that using Magento's event-driven architecture for this purpose is overkill. With any module install you are necessarily touching the database. Rather than have a generic observer looking at all module installs, you should implement your own resource setup class which extends from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` - several core modules do this. In this custom setup resource class you can perform any task for which you are currently considering (sending an email, logging some info, writing an additional record to the DB, etc.).  From here it will be up to you and your developers to require that each new payment module use this setup resource to install payment modules.

Comment: "each new payment module use this setup resource to install payment modules" - it's not a "good" way (I think). But still it's a good answer.

Comment: Why is this not a good solution? Your other option is to repeat your payment module registration logic in each module's install file (which violates *DRY*). Also, this implementation pattern exists in Magento core.

In each payment module, define `global/resources/your_module_setup/setup/class=Your_Module_Model_Resource_Setup`. In this class, override `_installResourceDb()` method to include your registration logic ahead of  `parent::_installResourceDb()`. Minimal impact, and it will only run when your module is installed.

Comment: Maybe there was little bit of incomprehension, but I think your solution will not work if module installed from Magento Connect. Please correct me if I'm wrong... I just want to hear more answers. I am really interested in doing it really _DRY_

Comment: Unfortunately there is no solution for you if you are doing this from Magento Connect.

Answer (score 1):

You might research about module installation. Particularly, all modules are inserted into database:

```
core_resource
```

Also I would suggest to start from:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
```

Also perhaps debug_backtrace() would help you. When you place your module first time you can backtrace how it was installed.

**UPDATE 1**

Try to trace following functions:

```
/**
 * Processing object after save data
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
protected function _afterSave()
{

/**
 * Callback function which called after transaction commit in resource model
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public function afterCommitCallback()
{

/**
 * Get array of objects transfered to default events processing
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getEventData()
{
```

Well please specify you last goal. Perhaps there is far more better solution than via observers.

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish _Payment method_ from _Non-Payment method_ module when it is installed?

Comment: Well first of all Payment method depends on Mage_Payment. Therefore perhaps there is no way of normal categorization modules. But you can set some specific logic in your modules. So when payment module is installed it tells to your Listener : "Hey, I am Payment method! Lets...."

Comment: Particularly, you should specify that your module depens on it.

Comment: "all Payment method depends on Mage_Payment" - its a good news, I'll see what I can do, but even now I understand that without modifying core files needed functionality will be not achieved (because _Payment method modules_ will still extend `Mage_Payment`, even if I'll rewrite `Mage_Payment`). If I suggest doing it a "good" way, my module must support third-party modules, which I will be not able to modify... Thanks for your answer. But I really want to hear more, maybe there is a better way...

Comment: Okey. Then: data is inserted into DB - means that special event is already fired. Moreover by event you should be able to get module, therefore check if it is your guy or not.

Comment: "if it is your guy or not" - sorry, it means "if module is payment module or not"? If I able to grab a module name - I can grab its classes (I hope) or one of them (model class I think) and if that class extends `Mage_Payment` I can precisely say that it is a payment method module - good Idea, Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not sure for 100%. Therefore you should test it.

Comment: @JakeTheFish Events do not fire during module install process. Moreover, the auto-fired events associated with data models come from `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, which `Mage_Core_Model_Resource` does not extend.